# Memory change detection function in C++ isn't detecting properly some malwares

Tags: c++, windows, memory-management

I'm having an anti cheat system for my private online game platformed for **Windows**.
One of the most popular functions I have is **memory change detection.**
*Source code for memory change detections:*

```
bool MEMORY_PROTECTION_INIT() // OK
{
    bool ClearFileMapping = 0;

    if((FileMappingHandle=CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,0,PAGE_READWRITE,0,sizeof(HACK_VERIFY_FILE_MAPPING),"Local\\HACK_VERIFY_FILE_MAPPING")) == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if(GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
    {
        ClearFileMapping = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        ClearFileMapping = 1;
    }

    if((lpHackVerifyFileMapping=(HACK_VERIFY_FILE_MAPPING*)MapViewOfFile(FileMappingHandle,FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,0,0,sizeof(HACK_VERIFY_FILE_MAPPING))) == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if(ClearFileMapping != 0)
    {
        lpHackVerifyFileMapping->Clear();
    }

    MemoryProtectionTime = GetTickCount();

    return 1;
}

bool MEMORY_PROTECTION_SCAN() // OK
{
    if(gMemoryGuardSwitch == 0 || (gMemoryGuardNumber & MEMORY_GUARD_NUMBER_INJECT) == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }


    for(DWORD n=0;n < lpHackVerifyFileMapping->WriteVirtualMemoryCount;n++)
    {
        HACK_VERIFY_FILE* lpHackVerifyFile = &lpHackVerifyFileMapping->WriteVirtualMemoryTable[n];

        if(lpHackVerifyFile->time >= MemoryProtectionTime)
        {
            if(lpHackVerifyFile->spid != GetCurrentProcessId())
            {
                
                if(lpHackVerifyFile->tpid == GetCurrentProcessId())
                {
                    CHClientDisconnectSend(CLIENT_DISCONNECT_MEMORY_DETECTION,0,lpHackVerifyFile->spid);
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 1;
}

bool HANDLE_PROTECTION_INIT() // OK
{
    CProcessQuery ProcessQuery;

    HANDLE HandleValue = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ,0,GetCurrentProcessId());

    if(ProcessQuery.Fetch(SystemExtendedHandleInformation,sizeof(SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFO_EX)) != 0)
    {
        SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFO_EX* lpSystemHandleInfo = ProcessQuery.GetExtendedHandleInfo();

        if(lpSystemHandleInfo != 0)
        {
            SYSTEM_HANDLE_ENTRY_INFO_EX* lpSystemHandleEntryInfo = lpSystemHandleInfo->Handles;

            if(lpSystemHandleEntryInfo != 0)
            {
                for(DWORD n=0;n < lpSystemHandleInfo->NumberOfHandles;n++,lpSystemHandleEntryInfo++)
                {
                    if(lpSystemHandleEntryInfo->UniqueProcessId == GetCurrentProcessId() && lpSystemHandleEntryInfo->HandleValue == ((DWORD)HandleValue))
                    {
                        HandleProtectionNumber = (DWORD)lpSystemHandleEntryInfo->ObjectTypeIndex;
                        HandleProtectionObject = (DWORD)lpSystemHandleEntryInfo->Object;
                        ProcessQuery.Close();
                        return 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ProcessQuery.Close();

    return 0;
}

bool HANDLE_PROTECTION_SCAN() // OK
{
    if(gMemoryGuardSwitch == 0 || (gMemoryGuardNumber & MEMORY_GUARD_NUMBER_HANDLE) == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    static CProcessQuery ProcessQuery;

    std::map<DWORD,std::vector<DWORD>> HandleProtectionTable;

    if(ProcessQuery.Fetch(SystemExtendedHandleInformation,sizeof(SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFO_EX)) != 0)
    {
        SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFO_EX* lpSystemHandleInfo = ProcessQuery.GetExtendedHandleInfo();

        if(lpSystemHandleInfo != 0)
        {
            SYSTEM_HANDLE_ENTRY_INFO_EX* lpSystemHandleEntryInfo = lpSystemHandleInfo->Handles;

            if(lpSystemHandleEntryInfo != 0)
            {
                for(DWORD n=0;n < lpSystemHandleInfo->NumberOfHandles;n++,lpSystemHandleEntryInfo++)
                {
                    if(lpSystemHandleEntryInfo->UniqueProcessId != GetCurrentProcessId() && lpSystemHandleEntryInfo->ObjectTypeIndex == HandleProtectionNumber && lpSystemHandleEntryInfo->Object == ((LPVOID)HandleProtectionObject) && (lpSystemHandleEntryInfo->GrantedAccess & PROCESS_VM_WRITE) != 0)
                    {
                        std::map<DWORD,std::vector<DWORD>>::iterator it = HandleProtectionTable.find(lpSystemHandleEntryInfo->UniqueProcessId);

                        if(it == HandleProtectionTable.end())
                        {
                            HandleProtectionTable.insert(std::pair<DWORD,std::vector<DWORD>>(lpSystemHandleEntryInfo->UniqueProcessId,std::vector<DWORD>(1,lpSystemHandleEntryInfo->HandleValue)));
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                        {


                            if(it->second.size() >= 10)
                            {
                                CHClientDisconnectSend(CLIENT_DISCONNECT_MEMORY_DETECTION,0,lpSystemHandleEntryInfo->UniqueProcessId);
                                return 0;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                it->second.push_back(lpSystemHandleEntryInfo->HandleValue);
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 1;
}

bool MEMORY_CHECK_ATTACH() // OK
{
    CCRC32 CRC32;

    MODULEINFO ModuleInfo;

    memset(&ModuleInfo,0,sizeof(ModuleInfo));

    if(GetModuleInformation(GetCurrentProcess(),GetModuleHandle(0),&ModuleInfo,sizeof(ModuleInfo)) == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS32* lpNtHeader = (IMAGE_NT_HEADERS32*)((DWORD)ModuleInfo.lpBaseOfDll+((IMAGE_DOS_HEADER*)ModuleInfo.lpBaseOfDll)->e_lfanew);

    IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER* lpSectionHeader = (IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER*)((DWORD)lpNtHeader+sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS32));

    for(int n=0;n < lpNtHeader->FileHeader.NumberOfSections;n++)
    {
        MEMORY_CHECK_SOURCE data;

        data.VirtualAddress = (DWORD)ModuleInfo.lpBaseOfDll+lpSectionHeader[n].VirtualAddress;

        data.VirtualSize = lpSectionHeader[n].Misc.VirtualSize;

        data.VirtualChecksum = CRC32.FullCRC((BYTE*)data.VirtualAddress,data.VirtualSize);

        MemoryCheckSource.insert(std::pair<DWORD,MEMORY_CHECK_SOURCE>(data.VirtualAddress,data));

        break;
    }

    return 1;
}

bool MEMORY_CHECK_DETACH() // OK
{
    CCRC32 CRC32;

    for(std::map<DWORD,MEMORY_CHECK_SOURCE>::iterator it=MemoryCheckSource.begin();it != MemoryCheckSource.end();it++)
    {
        if(it->second.VirtualChecksum != CRC32.FullCRC((BYTE*)it->second.VirtualAddress,it->second.VirtualSize))
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

For some reasons it works fine on some malwares, but some software (that are doing memory changes too) aren't detected by the function.
After few checks I realized that the difference between both types of cheats is the **memory base address**.
For those that are **detected by the function**- the base address that is calling to Heap(id2) is **0x30000**. Although the software that **aren't detected by the function**- the base address that is calling to heap(id2) (- same use) is **0x10000** (the first one).

any ideas what changes should I make to make sure that these cheats are blocked?

Comment: This looks very platform-specific (and I assume the platform is Windows based on all the non-standard type names and the Hungarian warts). It might be worth tagging the question appropriately.

Comment: @UniqueMU: Commenting doesn't give reputation.  It did, however, lead to a better set of tags on the question which will help it find the people interested in and knowledgeable about the topic.

Comment: I also found out that one of the common things to undetected softwares that they have handle to game.exe so I wanted to make a check: for all processes, for all handles- if handle type is process && handle name is game.exe - return true;
how can I get a handle type & name of process it runs on?